# What is the most efficient way to multiply (term by term) rows of matrix

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a matrix `A`. And I wanna get a values `B = A(i, :) .* A(j, :)` and `C = X .* A(i, :)` where `i` and `j` are some 1 x 1 numbers. Is there any faster way to do it?

I asked this because of nonefficient indexing in matlab.

Comment: Are those `i,j` loop iterators?

Comment: Are you ascking about cycles (i and j)?

Comment: Yes, are you using those calculations inside two nested loops with i and j as the loop iterators? Because if `i` and `j` are just one-off scalars, there isn't anything wrong with what you have already.

Comment: i and j are scalars which apears randomly. And I think than if-else trees and arrays instead of matrix can be more efficient. Just my first opinion, I didn't execute any tests. But such trees too massive for my code so I try to find out another way.

Comment: So, i & j are two sets of values, right? Are you calculating B and C with them inside some loop? Why not show more of those IF-ELSE code that you have there. Just those two minimal codes won't give us a good idea on what you are *really* trying to achieve.

Comment: `if i == 1 & j == 1 C = r1 .* r1`
`elseif i == 1 & j == 2 C = r1 .* r2`
`elseif i == 5 & j == 3 C = r5 .* r3`
and so on where `A = [r1; r2...]`
Besides that I can make from such if-else tree binary tree in order to get log N instead of N
I think it will work faster. But it can make my code too massive

Comment: What do you mean by "nonefficient indexing"? I don't think there's any reason to think that what you are doing is inefficient, and certainly going through a whole bunch of conditional statements to only repeat the same calculation isn't going to help. For any useful answer you will need to provide more code so we can see how it runs.

Comment: I'm looking for code improvement, not algorithm improvement. But thanks all who answered.